# How can daisy-chain Django model's reverse foreign key from a staticmethod?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose I have 3 Django models:

```
class MyModelA(models.Model):
    my_int = models.IntegerField()

    @staticmethod
    def my_Astatic_method():
        return "AHello"

class MyModelB(models.Model):
    my_int = models.IntegerField()
    my_a = models.ForeignKey(MyModelA, related_name="MyModelB_a")


    @staticmethod
    def my_Bstatic_method():
        return "BHello"

class MyModelC(models.Model):
    my_int = models.IntegerField()
    my_b = models.ForeignKey(MyModelB, related_name="MyModelC_b")

    @staticmethod
    def my_Cstatic_method():
        return "CHello"
```

I have an instance of `MyModelA` called `a`. From within a method of `a`, I would like to call `my_Cstatic_method()`. How can I do it?

`a.MyModelB_a.model.my_Bstatic_method()` works to call `MyModelB`'s static method:

```
>>> a.MyModelB_a.model.my_Bstatic_method()
'BHello'
```

But I don't know how to get one level down into `MyModelC`'s static methods from `MyModelB`'s `model` attribute. How should I do it?

Surprisingly, there is no `model` attribute for the object `a.MyModelB_a.model.MyModelC_b`:

```
>>> dir(a.MyModelB_a.model.MyModelC_b)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__set__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'related', 'related_manager_cls']
```

Comment: if you call a. MyModelB_a(), will return a lot of MyModelB instances, alright?
To have access to a MyModelC, you need get one MyModelB instances and call the related_name MyModelC_b, and then get one of C instance to call my_Cstatic_method

Comment: Something like this, should work :
a.MyModelB_a.first().MyModelC_b.model.my_Cstatic_method()

Comment: Doesn't that assume that there are instances of `MyModelB`? What if there are none? These are static methods. They should be on the model itself, not on instances. So I would hope the solution doesn't rely on the existance of instances. Right?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'll try here.

Comment: I think you could only run the B method, because of the instance of the 'a'

Comment: Hmmm. I think you might be correct about that :(